# Which version of Drools to use with JDK 1.7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, drools, java-ee-7, rule-engine

For a legacy  Java EE project I have to work with JDK 1.7 Since I want to add drools for managing business rules,  I'd like to know which is the latest drools release I can use for this project.

I have tried with the following versions, and I can not compile the examples included in the release:

6.5, 6.2, 6.1, 6.0, 5.6, 5.5

Error: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

This is my builpath:
[image]

My JAVA_HOME is set to 1.8:

[image]

Could this be the cause of the problem? or is the drools release incompatibility with JDK 1.7

A lot of Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493865/why-isnt-drools-working-with-java-8#22501455) and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121257/drools-java-7-support-in-eclipse#10132981)

Comment: This is typically the error you get when you try to execute using v1/.../java x.class a class file (x.class) that has been compiled using v2/.../javac x.java where v2 produces a later (higher major) class file version than v1 can execute. Make sure to compile everything using 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjust the compliance level works for my, i work with JDK 1.7 and Drools Release 6.50 Final:

builtpath:
[image]

JDK compliance:
[image]

Test:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Drools 5.x should work fine with JDK 1.7.

As others have mentioned, and to answer your other question, you will need to compile your project against JDK 1.7 instead of 1.8.

Some additional information about your error "Error: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" can be found in this post:

[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)